# assign displayName to react static component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How to give Title component a name? I tried Title.displayName below it I got an error.

```
class Menu extends Component {
  static Title = ({ children, handleTabClick }) => {
    return (
      <div className="title" onClick={handleTabClick}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  };
  //Title.displayName = 'title' //won't work

  render() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child)
    )
  }
}
```

Unless I declare Title outside of the class, otherwise I've no idea how to give a name to it.

Answer (score 1):

Function `name` and `displayName` properties exist for debugging purposes and aren't necessary. Usually they can be disregarded in favour of leaner code.

In case `name` is desirable, it can be:

```
class Menu extends Component {
  static Title = function Title({ children, handleTabClick }) {
    return (
      <div className="title" onClick={handleTabClick}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  };
  ...
```

Or just:

```
class Menu extends Component {
  static Title({ children, handleTabClick }) {
    return (
      <div className="title" onClick={handleTabClick}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
  ...
```

`name` is enough for debugging, and [`displayName` is non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/displayName) and isn't used by default in most browsers.

It's possible to conveniently assign a property to static method via a decorator (the way it's assigned may vary if this is instance method):

```
function displayName(name) {
  return (target, prop, descriptor) => { 
    target[prop].displayName = name;
  };
}

class Menu extends Component {
  @displayName('Title')
  static Title({ children, handleTabClick }) {
    return (
      <div className="title" onClick={handleTabClick}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
  ...
```